# vector<string *> confuses me

Tags: c++, stl

Say I need to store long strings in my vector. I can declare it as vector. However the better approach would be to store pointers to those strings and not the actual strings.

So should my declaration be something like vector & simply I do something like:

```
LOOP
//Accept String from a file in myString
vector<string *> v1;
string * sample = &myString;
v1.push_back(sample);
END LOOP
```

Is this appropriate or their exists a better way to achieve this? I may even be wrong completely out here.

Comment: One problem, your vector is local to your loop and thus will go *poof* at the end of every iteration.

Comment: "However the better approach would be to store pointers...", why is this a better approach?

Comment: You could do that, but you have to make sure that myString remains a valid object any time you want to access the pointer in the vector

Comment: If you do like this, and change the value of `myString` then all the pointer to it will "change" as well, as they all point to the same object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no reason to store pointers to strings.  `std::string` will use heap allocated memory for "long" strings anyway, so the only thing to gain by storing pointers in your container is the headache of managing the memory yourself.

On the other hand, if you need copies of those long strings in multiple locations, you could keep shared pointers to the strings in the vector:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>>;
```

Answer (score 4):

> However the better approach would be to store pointers to those strings and not the actual strings.

I really doubt that. Unless you have really good reasons to use the pointers, use `std::vector<std::string>` instead.